# Migration tool Windows 7 to Window 10 computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Note: I've seen a number of older, similar questions, with no applicable answer. I am a Mac owner, so my knowledge of PCs is very limited.

My sister in law has a PC currently running windows 7. Just finished her taxes for her, and the message at the end was "we are no longer supporting Windows 7, please update to do your 2020 taxes next year." Given how old her computer is, and the fact that I can buy her a used PC running windows 10 cheaper than buying the OS alone, I told her it's time to get her the newer PC.

When adding a Mac to my collection, I've used "Migration Assistant" which easily moves all applications and data to the new Mac. If the OS is the same, I can expect all software to function fine, if the OS is newer, of course, some may not work.

I am looking to see if such an application is part of Windows 10, if not, is there a recommended process to do this?

Comment: What exactly is giving the message it does not support Windows 7?  There are various tools that exist to migrate a user profile from one machine to another.

Comment: I use TurboTax for my taxes. The tax software itself gave this as a message, once the return was filed. As a warning for next year.  It offered the same warning filing my own return on my Mac.

Comment: I use Turbo Tax myself.  From the support requirements:  What are the minimum system requirements for the CD or download edition of TurboTax?
Processor: 1 GHz or faster.
Operating System: Windows 10 or Windows 8.
Internet Browser: Internet Explorer 9.0 or later.
Memory: 512 MB RAM or more.
Hard Disk Space: 300 MB free hard drive space.  If the Windows 7 machine is old enough, replace it with a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Yes, that is what prompted my question. I would like to buy my sister-in-law a new computer and move her files and whatever applications will still work under windows 10.

Comment: Collect her files on a USB hard drive (USB SSD drive) and then assess what software she has. Upgrade old software and use whatever existing software works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has no migration structure anything like macOS has.

The best it can offer is OneDrive - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/transfer-your-data which any Mac user will find hugely disappointing by comparison… or a USB stick. It's all a bit manual, I'm afraid.

Alternatively, you're looking at 3rd party apps, such as [Laplink PCMover](https://pcmover-10.laplink.com) [You need the paid version before it's any more use than a USB stick]

You could buy her a Mac instead ;) At least that way you'd have no trouble with the migration, as the Mac can do that from Windows as well as from another Mac. It can't unfortunately migrate the apps, but it can everything else, docs, mail etc.

Comment: Funny you say that. When I got the message “you need Mojave next year”, I had the choice of updating my Mac Pro video card for about $300 or buying a 2012 Mac mini to run the OS. The Mini was $350, and I bought it.

Comment: Mhm, yup. I put a 200 buck GPU in one of the Pros, the others are slowly falling behind from current OS. I can't yet envision a mini with 14TB of RAID hung off the back, so I'm sticking with the old Pros for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

If a PC is over 5 years old, I recommend buying a new PC.

As of two weeks ago, the upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 was still free.

Without exception, I get better performance from old PCs by doing
a clean/fresh install of Windows 10 instead of doing an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Planning to buy a new(we) pc. Hers is old enough, I don’t think it’s worth the effort to try to update to windows 10 on this one.